# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'me') (DISCORD JS)

Tags: discord, discord.js

```js
  client.on('message', async message => {
let guild = message.guild
if (!guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return
})
```

When my bot join a server, there is this error

````js
if (!guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'me')
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Todoroki/index.js:236:16)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found out how to do. I just added:

```js
let guild = message.guild
if (!guild) return;
// rest of commands
```

Answer (score 1):

That means that the command is runned on a server. Or you don't have the GUILDS intents enabled. simply

```js
client.on('message',message =>{
  if(!message.guild) return;
  // Do whatever you want
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Without much information, I could only deduce that `me` is `null`. To solve it, you could check if `guild.me` is `truthy` using [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like so:

`if (!guild?.me?.hasPermission ...`

Comment: there is the same error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'me')`

for 


`if (guild.me && !guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return`

Comment: Sorry I might be mistaken here, but could you check if "guild" is null or undefined?

Comment: @Sans I've edited my answer. Might help you. Anyway, I see that you've already resolved your problem. Cool!